# trying to write a loop in one line

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, python-3.3

I'm using python 3.3
i have been trying to write this line in one line and I can't manage.

```
   plop = []
   for i in range (len(list1)):
      if list1[i] != list1[i-1]:
           plop.append(list1[i])
```

I don't care overwriting list1 if needed, and not using "plop" at all, I don't want to use set as well.
Thanks!

p.s edited was a typo, sorry

Comment: As @JonClements pointed out, your code compares `list1[0]` with `list1[-1]` on the first step, and so `[1,2,1]` will produce `[new_ls[1], new_ls[2]]`.  Is that intended, or is that a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much more readable (and not so prone to index errors - unless you are meant to be comparing the first element with the last, and the second with the first etc...) way of removing consecutive duplicates is if you just did:

```
from itertools import groupby
plop = [k for k, g in groupby(list1)]
```

And of course, you could "one line it" :)

```
from itertools import groupby; plop = [k for k, g in groupby(list1)]
```

Or, if not using a set, and there can't be any duplicates - contiguous or not:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
plop = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1))
```

Comment: *grumble* I was about to write the `OrderedDict` case, which is what I use in practice if the elements are hashable.  Your `groupby` solution is more general.

Comment: @DSM What I tend to do is keep an up to date copy of `more_itertools` now and then use the `unique_everseen` recipe instead of the `OrderedDict` but yeah... good point about elements having to be hashable... And I suppose it's fair to add that when using `groupby` - the elements have to be orderable :)

Comment: He seems to be picking elements from _another_ list if there's no duplicate (of course that may be a typo), that's why I went the comprehension route. If it's a typo, yes, it's better not to duplicate what's built in.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ahhhh.... very good spot - that'd be something completely different... and a little strange... so it would be handy if that were clarified though :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the 'single line' requirement, but you could do it using a comprehension;

```py
plop = [new_ls[i] for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] != list1[i-1]]
```

...or if you're not really meaning to compare the first and the last element for the first value;

```
plop = [v for (x,y,v) in zip(list1, [None]+list1, new_ls) if x != y]
```